# QR Code generated by libraries are not readable by QR Scanners - looking for reliable way to generate QR code

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to generate qr code in my application.

I tried several answers on stack overflow

[How can I generate multiple values QR code in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54608164/9640177)
[Generate designer 2d QR code in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28827407/9640177)

I could generate QR code using this library - https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen

But the qr code scanner can not read the qr code generated by this library, though it is able to read other qr codes.

Any reliable way to generate qr codes on android app???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Using QRGen , you can directly use the **Zxing** library in your android application , and use this code which is shown below to generate the QRcode

```
 QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
try {
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
    int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_result_qr)).setImageBitmap(bmp);

} catch (WriterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to Add the Zxing library to your project, you can paste this into your gradle dependency file

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: testing now. Can I get the source code??? Should be there on github?